# How to return the length of a collection to insert into DOM with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I wonder if someone knows how to return the length of a collection both before and after a change to its number of models.  I need to use that value to replace the contents of a div on the page.

The collection is:

```
window.CourtTracks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CourtTrack,

    courtLoc : function( location ) {
        return _(this.filter( function( data ) {
            return data.get( "court" ) == location;
        }));
    }

});
```

In a separate backbone.view, I have loaded the collection with model data and then filtered it using the filter above.

```
var coll = new CourtTracks(alt);
var cnt = coll.courtLoc( location );
```

When I ask for *cnt.length* the value is returned as *undefined*.  *coll.length* is however, returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return this.filter( function( data ) {...})
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/dira/qhFWp/

Answer (score 0):

collections have a length() method on them

```
myCollection.length(); //=> x
myCollection.add(myModel);
myCollection.length(); //=> x + 1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I didn't give enough detail and have added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to `bind` `courtLoc` to the collection object? Set a breakpoint inside that method and verify that `this` is what you think it ought to be.